# How update php.ini on a Mac OS X Mojave?

Tags: php, apache, macos-mojave, php-ini, memory-limit

I'm on Mac OS X Mojave

*Step 1*

I ran

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

I got

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/php5/lib
Loaded Configuration File => /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
```

*Step 2*

I open up the ini file

```
vi /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini , 

and update memory_limit to -1
```

[image]

*Step 3*

I ran

```
php -i | grep memory_limit
```

I got

```
memory_limit => 256M => 256M
```

*Step 4*

I restart my

```
sudo apachectl -k restart
```

and type in my password

and tried

```
php -i | grep memory_limit
```

again, I still got

```
memory_limit => 256M => 256M
```

Seems like my chages never take any effect ...

Do I need to start any service on a Mac? If so, what command to do that?

**phpinfo**

[image]

Comment: cli and apache uses different config files run phpinfo() to see which config file is used by the apache

Comment: You do not need to restart Apache to see php.ini changes take effect on CLI, your change should work just as you've demonstrated. All I can think is maybe use 0 instead of -1? Seems the PHP site is down right now so I can't confirm.

Comment: Hah read this: https://serverfault.com/questions/295584/php-cli-memory-limit in cli it's simply ignored the memory_limit

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Create an empty php file with:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Load it with your web browser (localhost/yourfile.php).

Check that:

1. "Loaded Configuration File" match the configuration file you changed.
2. "memory_limit" has the value it is supposed to have.

---

I usually install a "clean" php using [Brew](https://brew.sh). So here a few questions to be sure:

1. Do you use php as cli or with Apache/Nginx? (It might be 2 config files)
2. If you're using Apache, did you restart it? (sudo apachectl -k restart)
3. Did you try with a more conventional value (like 2048M)? I'm not sure -1 is always supported.

Comment: 1 - I use Apache, sorry forgot to added that in the tag of the post

Comment: 2 - yes it will restart it.

Comment: 3 - I have not try anything other than -1 yet

Comment: Could you check the path of your config file with : <?php phpinfo(); ?> (in a php file served by apache)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.

The PHP INI file which you have edited and the INI file that is loaded in Apache server is different..

You have to update the PHP loader in the apache `httpd.conf` file.

After that restart the apache server with `sudo apachectl restart`.

Finally, now you can test the PHP ini file loaded in apache2 with `phpinfo();`

Answer (score 0):

Though It is old question still many people struggle. So thought to answer it.

- Installed php.ini is located at  /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini (or it
  can be at  /usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini )
- php.ini used by Apache
  are different, which is /etc/php.ini.

  vi /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini

so above changes to php.ini does not reflect in Apache. Solution is to point to correct PHP in your apache config file.

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Search for pattern "LoadModule php" and comment the existing line with libexec and add below line to your installation.

```
#LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.3/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so
```

Restart your apache

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

Check log file

```
tail -f  /var/log/apache2/error_log
```