# Update memory_limit of PHP.ini - Mac OS X Mojave

Tags: php, macos, apache, macos-mojave, php-ini

## I've tried

the steps below, but doesn't seem to take effect.

---

## I created

a file `index.php` at `/Users/bheng/Sites/info`

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

## I added

a virtual host

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/bheng/Sites/info"
  ServerName phpinfo.test
  UseCanonicalName Off
</Virtualhost>
```

## I saw

to `http://phpinfo.test/` I see phpinfo page load up

[image]

Location of the `php.ini` showed that it's at `/etc/`

[image]

## I went

to `/etc` in my Terminal

```
⚡️  etc  ls | grep php                                                                                                                                                       
php-fpm.conf.default                                                                                                                                                        
php-fpm.d/                                                                                                                                                                  
php.ini.default                                                                                                                                                             
php.ini.default-5.2-previous                                                                                                                                                
php.ini.default-5.2-previous~orig                                                                                                                                           
php.ini.default-previous                                                                                                                                                    
php.ini.default-previous~orig                                                                                                                                               
⚡️  etc  ls | grep ini                                                                                                                                                       
mach_init.d/                                                                                                                                                                
mach_init_per_login_session.d/                                                                                                                                              
mach_init_per_user.d/                                                                                                                                                       
php.ini.default                                                                                                                                                             
php.ini.default-5.2-previous                                                                                                                                                
php.ini.default-5.2-previous~orig                                                                                                                                           
php.ini.default-previous                                                                                                                                                    
php.ini.default-previous~orig
```

As you can see, I don't see `php.ini` there at all.

The only thing that closes to that is `php.ini.default`

## I opened

that file, and update memory_limit to 4G.

Nothing seem to take effect, it kept show 128 MB on the site.

---

I just want to update the **memory_limit** from 128 MB to **4** GB

**Any hints for me ?**

[image]

Comment: Check your web server setting as to where it looks for the php.ini file, and it looks like you do not have a php.ini file so you should make a copy of the default, change the name, then make your changes to it.

Comment: There should be a `Loaded Configuration File` item in your config page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How update php.ini on a Mac OS X Mojave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871717/how-update-php-ini-on-a-mac-os-x-mojave)

Comment: @brunorey I saw `/etc` but I don't see it there.

Comment: Please post the 'Loaded Configuration File' from phpinfo();

Comment: It showed that it's at `/etc/`

Comment: What you showed is `Configuration file path`, not `Loaded Configuration File`

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: @kyo looks like you need to restart the PHP-FPM process pool. See answer below.

Comment: see my first comment and make a php.ini file and restart your web server.

Comment: It’s /etc/ see the image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, look at phpinfo's output for the value of **Loaded Configuration File**. Also take a look at the section titled **Additional .ini files parsed**. You'll need to check any and all INI files listed there to see if they might have a **memory_limit** value that is over-writing your setting.

> The only thing that closes to that is php.ini.default

I believe **php.ini.default** is just a fallback file that you can use to create a new PHP.ini file if you need to. Check the output of phpinfo as instructed above to determine which ini files are actually processed.

EDIT: Just seeing now that your phpinfo output says **None** next to **Loaded Configuration File**. I'd suggest copying that php.ini.default file to the location specified in **Configuration File (php.ini) path** which in your case is `/etc`. Note that this is a pretty awkward place for this file. PHP.ini is usually located somewhere like `/etc/php7.0/` or `/etc/php7.0/apache/` or something like that. However, your PHP executable is looking for it in `/etc` so copy the file there:

`sudo cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini`

Finally, if you are running PHP-FPM (which it looks like you are from your **ls** command above) then you need to restart the PHP-FPM process pool.  I'm not sure the exact command on your machine but this works on mine:

`sudo service php7.0-fpm restart`

What works on your machine will probably depend on how you installed PHP-FPM. You might also try:

`service php-fpm restart`

EDIT: You might also consider restarting apache. This will also depend on the installation method you have used. On my Ubuntu machine, this command works

`sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: @arivero that's a good question. To restart apache, try `sudo apachectl restart`. I honestly don't know how to restart php-fpm on OSX. If you used brew to install it, [you might try something like this](https://gist.github.com/devdrops/c96c87dc3f32f6f3d2132ed89c227913).

Answer (score 0):

What you actually have to do is copy the php.ini.default file from /etc and create a new file php.ini on the same path. There you can make changes.